# Command meaning of the command (nl /etc/passwd | tail -n +25 )

Tags: command-line

What is the meaning of this command? `nl /etc/passwd | tail -n +25`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Really in `nl /etc/passwd | tail -n +25`  you have two commands with pipe:

1. `nl` will number the lines of the given filename `/etc/passwd`
2. `|` is pipe, it passes output from left command to the input of right command
3. `tail -n +25` will show tail of the file skipping 25 first lines.

So the output will start from 25th line and will end with the last line from of the `/etc/passwd` file.

---

Documentation to read:

- `man nl` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/nl.1.html)
- `man tail` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/tail.1.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot.
This is so well detailed explanation.